# Get the HttpContext.Current upon dependency Resolution Unity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, unity-container

How will I get the HttpContext.Current in the UnityConfig? It turns Out to be null on upon the start of the Application. I need to have the current URL of the application upon Dependency resolution. Here Goes my code

```
public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
      {
        // NOTE: To load from web.config uncomment the line below. Make sure to add a Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration to the using statements.
        // container.LoadConfiguration();
        //this is null
        var http = HttpContext.Current;
        container
            //add additional constructor to support the HostHelper of current set up
           .RegisterType<IDataContextAsync, OEPDataContext>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager(), new InjectionConstructor(HostHelper.GetConfiguration()))
           .RegisterType<IUnitOfWorkAsync, UnitOfWork>(new PerRequestLifetimeManager())
           .RegisterType<IRepositoryAsync<Menu>, Repository<Menu>>()
           .RegisterType<IMenuService, MenuService>();
        // TODO: Register your types here
        // container.RegisterType<IProductRepository, ProductRepository>();
    }
```

Comment: Can you expand on the scenario?  How exactly are you using the HttpContext?  Is it to determine what registrations to perform or inject HttpContext values when resolving or...?

Comment: @RandyLevy It will Get the current Uri so that i can Inject a proper Connection string to the context. basically it checks where the app is deployed either, Dev, Local, or Production based on the Url of the application.